# How to avoid differences in the heights of the lines of a beamer frame title?

Tags: beamer, positioning, frame-title

The following MWE points out that (see `beamer`'s documentation page 84)

> slight, but annoying differences in the heights of the lines

of a `beamer` frame title sometimes do happen (visible pages 2-3). A possible solution is to use e.g. the `overlayarea` environment but that leads to a frame title:

- top aligned even without any frame subtitle (see pages 3-4),
- too much top aligned compared to frames with subtitles (see pages 6-7).

Do you know how to avoid these differences and let frame titles at their natural vertical locations?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{%
    Foo
    \only<2>{bar}%
    \only<3>{(baz)}%
  }
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{5cm}
    Foo
    \only<2>{bar}%
    \only<3>{(baz)}%
    \end{overlayarea}
  }
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{%
    Foo
    \only<2>{bar}%
    \only<3>{(baz)}%
  }
  \framesubtitle{Baz}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The base default template for `frametitle` has struts, but some outer themes use their own default template, which hasn't them.

Comment: @egreg I don' see any strut in `\frametitle`'s definition in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`. Where are they?

Comment: `beamerouterthemedefault.sty`, lines 151-171

Comment: @egreg Indeed but, AFAICS, the `Rochester` theme used in my MWE hasn't its own default template for `frametitle` (see `beamerthemeRochester.sty`).

Comment: Following things in `beamer` is an interesting business

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as your titles don't have anything much bigger than a bracket, adding a strut will ensure they all have the same height:

```
\let\zzz\frametitle
\def\frametitle#1{\zzz{\strut\ignorespaces#1}}
```

Comment: Would it be worth `\frametitle`'s definition by default contain such a strut?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I'll ping Joseph, it's not my call:-)

Comment: Joseph's attention [drawn](https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issues/338/differences-in-the-heights-of-the-lines-of) :)